# Trigger Onclick Handler Onload By Accident

Tags: android, android-webview, android-5.0-lollipop

I have the following class that triggers on onclick handler onload by accident.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private WebView w;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    w.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    w.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    w.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    w.loadUrl("http://dus.tn/music.html");

    w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { public void onPageFinished(WebView w, String url) {
        String s = "javascript:"
          + "(function () {"
          + "  try{document.body.style.color='blue';del();}catch(e){}"
          + "})();";
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
          w.evaluateJavascript(s, null);
        else w.loadUrl(s);
      }
    });
  }
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    if(w.canGoBack())w.goBack();
    else super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

The html code is [here](https://gist.github.com/limeblack/f71d33c6153faa41c79f64f53a55fe1f) while also posted at dus.tn/music.html.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I'm not sure why the onlick event is triggering but adding the following appears to work.

```
function del(a){
  if(this == window)return;
  if (window.confirm("Delete?")) { 
    $(a).parent().remove();
  }
}
```

and the following

```
<a class=del href="#del" onclick="del.call(this,this);return false">X</a>
```